# Accessing AFP fileserver (netatalk) from Windows machine

Tags: windows, mac, afp, file-server, netatalk

One of our clients has a Mac environment. We are building (right now testing) a fileserver for Mac environments on a Linux box using netatalk. Netatalk uses AFP.

For testing purposes, I've installed Netatalk on an OpenSuse VM. My main problem is I don't have a Macintosh or any Apple machine (I am planning to get one).

I am wondering if there is any application/solution available on Windows, using which I can access this file server using AFP protocol (rather than using SMB), so it would be like accessing from actual Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Although there are solutions available, they're not suitable for the kind of testing you're probably trying to do.

One of the biggest hassles of using AFP file servers in Mac OS X is that, if you want file owner/group permissions to work, your server and all of the Mac client machines must use the same User ID and Group ID numbers for each user and group. This effectively means all your Mac clients must be bound to the same Open Directory (read: LDAP with some Apple-specific schema extensions) server as your file server is bound to, AND all the users must log into their client Macs' GUIs using their Open Directory account, not some local user account (local user accounts usually all have the same UIDs: 501, 502, etc. ).

If you were to test your server from Windows, you *might* find similar issues, but you'd also be struggling with Active Directory integration issues, rather than Open Directory. So you might be mostly wasting your time.